# How do I update the password for one of our administrators

Tags: passwords

One of our contacts has been made an administrator but they have forgotten their password. How can we update their password so that they can log in?

Comment: are you using CiviCRM Spark (ie the monthly service) rather than your own installation?

Answer (score 2):

CiviCRM does not have its own authentication tools per ce (well, perhaps except its [stand-alone version](https://docs.civicrm.org/installation/en/latest/standalone/)). Therefore password rescue should happen at your CMS (WordPress, Drupal, Joomla) level.